# Mysql query update (remove comma string)

Tags: replace, trim, concatenation

**MYSQL ROW :**

ID : 1

DATA : ,1,11,5

i wanna remove only ,1

**MYSQL QUERY :**

UPDATE  SET DATA=TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', DATA, ','), ',1,', ',')) WHERE ID='1';

**MYSQL RESULT** : 11,5

**NEED RESULT :** ,11,5

Answer (score 0):

**I was able**

UPDATE TABLE SET DATA=TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(' ', DATA, ','), ',1,', ',')) WHERE ID=1

**MYSQL RESULT** ,11,5

it's working

Comment: Your answer is or should be incorrect as there should be empty space " ,11,5", also the combination of `TRIM BOTH` and `CONCAT` from both sides kinda loose meaning. From what I can think of right now, there are 2 ways to do this: `UPDATE TABLE SET DATA=TRIM(BOTH ',,' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',,', DATA, ',,'), ',1,', ',')) WHERE ID=1`

Comment: and the other one is: `UPDATE TABLE SET DATA=TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(DATA, ','), ',1,', ',')) WHERE ID=1`